# How to take batch input in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I want my Matlab program to take batch input. That is from the current directory, my program will read all wav files with name 1-1, 1-2, 2-1, 2-2 upto M-1 and M-2. M will be taken as input also. How can I accomplish this? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`dir`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dir.html) in combination with a `for` loop.  `dir` allows you to search for all file names that pertain to a pattern.  In your case, you want to search for all `.wav` files.  First, specify where your `.wav` files are located, then in a loop, you can either process each sound signal independently, or you can stack them all together in a cell array.  I'm assuming that all of your sound files are unequal in length, which is why I suggest a cell array.

So, do either this:

```
loc = '/path/to/my/files'; %// Specify directory here
f = dir([loc '/*.wav']); %// Search for files

%// For each file....
for idx = 1 : numel(f)
    %// Read in audio from file
    d = fullfile(loc, f(idx).name);
    [y,Fs] = audioread(d);

    %// y contains your signal... do something with it
    %//...
    %//...
end
```

Or, you can do this:

```
loc = '/path/to/my/files'; %// Specify directory here
f = dir([loc '/*.wav']); %// Search for files

%// Specify cell array to contain all of your sound signals
out = cell(1, numel(f));

%// For each file....
for idx = 1 : numel(f)
    %// Read in audio from file
    d = fullfile(loc, f(idx).name);
    [y,Fs] = audioread(d);

    %// y contains your signal... add this to the cell array
    out{idx} = y;
end

%// out contains all of your sound signals, so do something with them
```

If you opt to do the second option, doing `out{idx}` accesses the sound at index `idx` in your cell array.

Comment: @Jason - No problem.  Let me know if this works.  If it does, I wouldn't mind if you accepted my answer.  Good luck!

Comment: @rayryeng: I strongly recommend `fullfile(loc, f(idx).name)` over [loc '/' f(idx).name]`.  `fullfile` makes your code portable.

Comment: @Jonas - Good suggestion.  I'll make that modification.